# How to remove keyboard tool bar in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, keyboard, flutter-layout, toolbar

I want remove keyboard tool bar.
However, the keyboard does not seem to have an attribute to remove the toolbar.
Please help me,,,,

[image]

Comment: you have to disable this from your emulator from setting and keyboard toolbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keyboard is separated app and you can't control it in any way. at least on Android you can try define [`android:inputType`](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style) hoping this bar disapear, but one keyboard-app may respect that, other may not. there is no reliable way

list of params for `inputType` is [HERE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:inputType). i.e. with `textPassword` this bar should be gone, but may also make `EditText` "asterisking" all chars